# jQuery .on() not firing no matter what event handler

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a website, nothing special, but I can't seem to get the .on() event to fire.
The HTML looks like this:

```
<fieldset class="movieField hide">
    <label for="selectedMovie">Next, select a movie:</label>
    <select id="selectedMovie" name="movie">
        <option disabled selected> -- select a movie -- </option>
        <option id="selectTamasha" value="AF">Tamasha</option>
        <option id="selectDino" value="CH">The Good Dinosaur</option>
        <option id="selectAlexEve" value="RC">Alex &amp; Eve</option>
        <option id="selectSpectre" value="AC">Spectre</option>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

and my jQuery looks like this:

```
$( 'form' ).on( 'change', '#selectedMovie', function()  {
   alert('f'); 
});
```

I've tried changing 'change' to 'mouseover' and 'click' but no difference.
Any ideas why this isn't working?

**EDIT**
New testing has revealed it works in Operah and firefox and IE but not Chrome. I know browsers work differently but this exact code works for a different element in chrome, why not this one?

**EDIT**
Cleared cache. Issue resolved. I have no idea why chrome picked up all the other changes I was doing but not this one.

Comment: Used `ready`, if the script is not at the end of `<body>`

Comment: You don't have a form tag.

Comment: ^ that, where's the form ?

Comment: I don't see a `form` element in your code.  Also, when are you executing this jQuery code?  Does a `form` element exist at that time?  (That is, is this code before or after a `form` element in your markup?)

Comment: Change your JQUERY statement to 

$( '#selectedMovie' ).on( 'change', function()  {
   alert('f'); 
});

Comment: what version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: .on jQuery click not working for dynamically created items

Comment: try `$(document.body).on('change','#selectedMovie',function(){`

Comment: Are you sure you included the jquery library?

Comment: First, inspect every error listed in Crome's console.

Comment: @f_martinez Yea I did before I turned to here. There wasn't any errors.

Comment: The fiddle with your example works as expected. So probably there are problems with environment. Maybe JS is totally turned off in Chrome's dev-tools for example.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the `form` tag.

try this:

```
$(document).on('change','#selectedMovie',function(){
    alert('F');
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bzcg3j2j/)

Comment: That didn't work. I also tried the inline onchange="runFunction()" and that didn't work either.
P.S. The form tag is there, it's just that including the entire form is a hell of a lot more code.

Comment: Then use pastebin or fiddle